# greendao sort by field in related table

Tags: android, greendao

is there a way to sort by a field in a related table with greenDao? E.g. I have a table of cars and a table of drivers. Each car has a driver. Now I want to query for ( e.g. blue ) cars and sort by the name of the driver

Answer (score 5):

In QueryBuilder, there are methods to specify the sorting order. Look for methods starting with "order...", e.g. orderAsc(Property).

Comment: Oh wait, we don't do joins yet. ;) Guess you have to write some custom  (raw) query for now.

Comment: yea just tried again after you answerd and got  de.greenrobot.dao.DaoException: Property 'foo' is not part of bar
Do you have an example on how to do it with a raw query?

Comment: order methods are not available on a querybuilder.join it seems

Answer (score 5):

I play around with GreenDao at the moment too and hope my little addition to the comment in the first answer and the description in the [queries part of the greenDao documentation](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/queries/) helps.

The following snippet should work (didn't test it :)):

```
Query query = carsDao.queryRawCreate(   ", driver D WHERE T.COLOR='blue' AND T.DRIVER_ID=D._ID ORDER BY D.NAME ASC");
```

This creates internally a SQL similiar to this:

```
SELECT T.'id', T.'name', T.'color', T.'driver_id'
FROM cars T, driver D
WHERE T.COLOR='blue'
AND T.DRIVER_ID=D._ID
ORDER BY D.NAME ASC
```

The first part of the statement is created for you by the queryRawCreate method, the rest is the custom sql statement which was passed to `queryRawCreate`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause) if you wonder where the JOIN statement is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use QueryBuilders with the (data access objects) DAOs that are generated by the Greendao ORM.

Define before you use (in Activities)

```
 ProductDao productDao;
 DaoSession daoSession;
```

You should place the DaoMaster and DaoSession in your application scope. Inside the onCreate() of the class that extends Application.

```
DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(getApplicationContext(), "app-db", null);
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
daoSession = new DaoMaster(db).newSession();
```

Initialize before you use

```
 daoSession = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getDaoSession();
 productDao = daoSession.getProductDao();
```

You can sort the results like this to display in the activity.

```
private void refreshProducts() {
        switch (sorted_by){
            case SORT_BY_DATE:
                cardItems = productDao.queryBuilder().orderAsc(ProductDao.Properties.Id).list();
                setupRecyclerView();
                break;

            case SORT_BY_PRICE:
                cardItems = productDao.queryBuilder().orderDesc(ProductDao.Properties.Price).list();
                setupRecyclerView();
                break;

            case SORT_BY_POPULARITY:
                cardItems = productDao.queryBuilder().orderDesc(ProductDao.Properties.Name).list();
                setupRecyclerView();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution with QueryBuilder.orderRaw() and Join.getTablePrefix()

My example code:

```
QueryBuilder.LOG_SQL = true;//Enable to see SQL result

  QueryBuilder<Item> query = daoSession.queryBuilder(Item.class);
  Join itemWithCollection = query.join(JoinItemWithCollection.class,
      JoinItemWithCollectionDao.Properties.ItemId);
  String joinedTable = itemWithCollection.getTablePrefix();
  Join collection = query.join(itemWithCollection, JoinItemWithCollectionDao.Properties.CollectionId,
      Collection.class, CollectionDao.Properties.Id);
  String orderCol = JoinItemWithCollectionDao.Properties.SomeOrderCol.columnName;
  collection.where(CollectionDao.Properties.Key.eq(collectionId));
  query.orderRaw(joinedTable+".\""+orderCol+"\" DESC");
  query.limit(limit);
  query.offset(from);

  List<Item> results = query.list();
```